# Como dividir uma string sprintf em múltiplas linhas no C?

Tags: c

Tenho uma um string no `sprintf` e gostaria de dividi-la em múltiplas linhas, pois ela acaba ficando grande e o código fica bagunçado.

```
sprintf(srt,"GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: text/javascript\r\nUser-Agent: Custom HTTP User Agent\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n, url, host);
```

Como eu poderia dividir isso em múltiplas linhas tornando o código mais organizado?
Como por exemplo:

```
GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n
Accept: text/javascript\r\n
User-Agent: Custom HTTP User Agent\r\n
Host: %s\r\n
Connection: Close\r\n
\r\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em C strings contantes e adjacentes são concatenadas. Então você pode dividir naturalmente sua string em várias partes, cada parte em uma linha, mas cada parte precisa ter suas próprias aspas.

Assim:

```
"GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Accept: text/javascript\r\n"
"User-Agent: Custom HTTP User Agent\r\n"
"Host: %s\r\n"
"Connection: Close\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

Comment: Quando a constante precisa de ser maior, é preciso saber os limites do compilador. O Standard de C impoe um limite mínimo de 509 caracteres em C89. Em C99 e C11 esse limite foi aumentado para 4095 caracteres.